# Need a list of languages that are supported completely by ASCII encoding

Tags: unicode, ascii

I am writing an article on Unicode and discussing the advantages of this encoding scheme over outdated methods like ASCII.

As part of my research I am looking for a reference that listed the languages that could be fully represented using only the characters supported by ASCII. Haven't had much luck tracking it down with Google and I thought I'd tap the collective knowledge of SO to see if anyone had a reasonable list.

### Key points:

- All languages listed must be able to
  be **completely** represented using the character set available in ASCII.
- I know this won't be comprehensive,
  but I am mostly interested in the
  most common written languages.

Comment: Are you asking for languages that do not permit Unicode characters, or languages that do not require Unicode characters?  The "completely represented" phrase doesn't mean much.  Even APL can be written in pure ASCII.  Can you define "completely represented"?

Comment: Are you sure it's ASCII you're talking about and not, say, ISO-8859-1? ASCII isn't adequate even for English.

Comment: Let me provide some context with an example. Let's say you have an application that encodes text as plain old legacy 8-bit ASCII, just like they taught us back in computer science class. I am looking for a list of natural languages that this app isn't likely to mangle.

Comment: There is no such thing as plain old legacy 8-bit ASCII. ASCII has always been and will always be 7-bit.

Comment: Most languages can be reasonably handled by specific 8-bit code pages. Multilingual code pages such as 850 or ISO 8859 can handle interchange between specified groups of languages. The 256 character limit of an 8-bit code page does not allow interchange between all language groups or representation of languages that use more than 256 characters or representation of many typographical glyphs.

Comment: Not what you had in mind but programming languages (C, Javascript, etc) and markup languages (HTML, XML, etc) are fully supported by ASCII.  They can even represent extended Unicode characters in text strings using only ASCII eg HTML and XML can do `&#x2038;` Javascript can do `\u2665`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no natural languages that I know of that can be fully represented in ASCII. Even American English, the language for which ASCII was invented, doesn't work: for one, there are a lot of foreign words that have been integrated into the American English language that cannot be represented in ASCII, like *resumé*, *naïve* or a word that probably every programmer uses regularly, *schönfinkeln*.

And two, ASCII is missing pretty much all typographic characters like “quotation marks”, dashes of various lengths (– and —), ellipses (…), thin and wide spaces and so on, all of which are used in American English.

Comment: Yep, though to nit-pick, three periods is the accepted normal form for typing an ellipsis. Unicode U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS is a compatibility character added to allow round-tripping to legacy encodings that had this as a single character.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. In German, that's generally not allowed, although everybody does it anyway, of course. Not everybody is obsessed like me and actually writes his own keyboard mapping with all those typographic characters :-)

Comment: This is just my opinion but English allows one to use the normalized version of all of these things. Two hyphens are accepted instead of a long dash for example. Most people also write resume or naive and don't use accented letters and we're all used to seeing that. So I guess the right question to ask is which languages accept normalization with only ASCII characters.

Comment: @PHPGuru: I don't think normalization will help you. It doesn't matter whether you use NFC, NFD, NFKC, or NFKD normalization, the issue still persists.

Comment: I meant normalization to ASCII with iconv or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

IIRC from my Latin classes, the macrons in Latin are later additions by people studying meters in Latin poetry; they wouldn't have been used in every-day writing. So you've got Latin.

Comment: I would never have thought of Latin, but you're right. Maybe the OP should specified *living* languages.

Comment: Lingua Latina mortua non est.

Answer (score 5):

Given loan words, I don't think there are *any* such languages.  Even ugly Americans know the difference between "resume" and "résumé".

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered the posibility of loaned words.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean natural languages and only 7 bit ASCII?

In that case the list is quite small. Mostly english.

Answer (score 2):

Some [constructed languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_constructed_languages) such as [Interlingua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingua) and [Ido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ido) are designed to use only ASCII characters. ‘Real’ languages in everyday use tend to use characters outside the ASCII range, at the very least for loanwords.

Answer (score 2):

Not a widely used language, but Rotokas can be written using only ASCII letters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotokas_alphabet

Comment: Also Hawai'an and Swahili.  I'm sure there are others.